# What does the destructor do silently?

Tags: c++, destructor

Considering the following code which looks like that the destructor doesn't do any real job, valgrind showed me clearly that it has memory leak without using the destructor. Any body can explain me what does the destructor do in this case?

```
#include <iostream>                                                                    
using namespace std;                                                                   

class A                                                                                
{                                                                                      
private:                                                                               
    int value;                                                                         
    A* follower;                                                                       
public:                                                                                
    A(int);                                                                            
    ~A();                                                                        
    void insert(int);                                                                  
};                                                                                     

A::A(int n)                                                                            
{                                                                                      
    value = n;                                                                         
    follower = NULL;                                                                   
}                                                                                      

A::~A()                                                                             
{                                                                                   
     if (follower != NULL)                                                           
         delete follower;                                                               
     cout << "do nothing!" << endl;                                             
}                                                                                   

void A::insert(int n)                                                                  
{                                                                                      
    if (this->follower == NULL) {                                                      
        A* f = new A(n);                                                               
        this->follower = f;                                                            
    }                                                                                  
    else                                                                               
        this->follower->insert(n);                                                     
}                                                                                      

int main(int argc, char* argv[])                                                       
{                                                                                      
    A* objectA = new A(1);                                                             

    int i;                                                                             
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                                           
        objectA->insert(i);                                                            

    delete objectA;                                                                    
}
```

Comment: silent but deadly.  it deletes the follower.

Comment: yes, but delete actually invoke the destructor defined which finally just do nothing, no?

Comment: I think that your destructor delete pointer "follower". You lost reference to value stored in memmory. But memmory is still allocated. So you can not access value and you waste your memmory space.

Comment: @zhanwu: The destructor doesn't just do nothing though does it. It calls delete on follower if it's non-null. That's the critical part.

Comment: Make a habbit of _always_ zero'ing pointers after deletion. That'll save you lots of frustrations in the future.

Comment: @ALevy: Or even better: use smart pointers that care of the deletion automatically whenever the pointer is "reset".

Comment: also 'cout << "do nothing!" << endl;' line is misleading. since it prints "do nothing" whether or not the destructor deletes the follower. just to let you know.

Comment: ...and instead of relying on pointer values or remembering to delete them. learn how to use different types of smart pointers that come with boost and stl.

Comment: @ALevy The delete is in the destructor.  There's no point in setting the pointer to null, since it is going out of scope immediately.

Comment: The test for null is unnecessary.  Deleting a null pointer is a valid operation

Comment: @James. That's why I used the term _habbit_ rather than _must_. NULLifying the pointer currently is indeed irrelevant, but should the developer (original or other) add code below that statement that uses the pointer, it would make things safer. As for the second statement, why would you try to delete a NULL pointer? Unless you're now sure whether it points to valid data or not, which is a problem by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The insert() method creates  new A on the heap and links it to the next element with the follower pointer.  So without the destructor on A, the object pointed to by follower never gets deleted.

Comment: I understand the result, but I don't understand how this is achieved since 'delete follower' invoke the destructor, which is not designed to do anything.

Comment: But it does do something. The fact that it prints out "do nothing!" is a red herring. When the destructor of A calls delete follower, it's freeing off the memory associated with the object A that was created by new in the insert method. It then also calls the destructor on that object (well it does that first). This then calls delete on the follower pointer of the second A object, all the way down the linked list. Hence deleting objectA in your main deleted all of the A objects in the linked list.

Comment: My understanding, if you define the destructor, then 'delete' invoke the user defined destructor, otherwise the compiler will make one for you. In my code, the destructor is defined in a way that it call itself or output something to cout. I don't see the part, how the the memory is freed.

Comment: Talking about the generated destructor, let say it frees the memory of an A object (pointed memory not included), it does the real thing; in case of my destructor, it just tell the object to ask its follower to "do something", the this "do something" finally turns out to be "cout"; and I think the my destructor is called INSTEAD of the compiler generated one but not TOGETHER WITH it, is this right?

Comment: If you define a ~A, then there is no compiler generated destructor. The key thing to understand is that actually deleting the memory for an instance of A is not the responsibility of the destructor. Calling delete a; where a is a pointer to A will delete the memory for the object pointed to by a whether or not there's a compiler generated destructor or one you've written yourself. However without the ~A you've written there's nothing to call delete on the follower pointer, so that object, and therefore anything it links to never gets deleted.

Comment: The compiler generated destructor for A won't automatically generate code consisting of "delete follower;" The compiler doesn't know that that memory must be deleted -- it could be a pointer to an object that A doesn't actually own. Hence you have to write your own destructor to manually call delete on follower. It is your responsibility to ensure that each object you explicitly create on the heap with new has a corresponding delete. You do that for the aObject pointer in main, but without the destructor on A there's nothing to delete the objects that are created on the heap in insert()

Answer (score 1):

First, let us hope this is for exercise, otherwise a `std::forward_list<int>` seems much more adequate (and a `vector<int>` would probably be better).

Second, the destructor role is, simply, to execute the code you put in it, which here is about releasing the resources acquired by `follower`.

The call to `delete follower` does two things:

- it calls the destructor of `follower`
- it then **release** the memory at which `follower` was stored

Without the call to `delete`, you have a memory leak.

Notes:

- Your class lacks a copy constructor and assignment operator
- It is not necessary, in `main`, to `new` the instance of `A`.

Comment: Given the semantics of the class, I'd probably ban copy and assignment.

Comment: @James: either ban or define them properly (after all, `std::forward_list` is copiable though at some expense), but definitely do something about them :)

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like the destructor does do real job: it deletes follower pointer, which calls ~A(), which, in turn will delete its follower and so on.

If you omit the destructor all allocated nodes will not be deleted.